# Question under review this long abnormal? @nohillside♦!? An update on "This Q needs details or clarity." as the closure reason? IT IS SOLVED

Tags: discussion, flagging

I have a question about my Ask Different post: [A too-big dialog window put up by AppleScript has made Safari unusable. (Why?) How can I dismiss it/recover, w/o losing unsaved content in open tabs?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/432370/a-dialog-window-put-up-by-applescript-has-made-safari-unusable-why-how-can-i)

My question was closed **at my request** (I presume, or in response to it, based on the sequence of events.)  I've addressed the shortcomings and explained that I HAVE AN ANSWER BUT CAN'T POST IT and indicated this days ago (18th; it's the 24th) and it remains under review and closed.

The boilerplate seems to not be about my question, too:

> "Needs details or clarity - sometimes we need more information in
> order to help solve your problem. Please clarify your specific problem
> or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's
> currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See
> the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.
>
> Edit your post to be more specific about what you're looking for, and
> be sure to address any concerns that other users brought up in the
> comments.

So, @nohillside♦, some help or more clearly valid guidance or reconsideration?

No users brought up any concerns.   I asked for the closure - I needed to test, and did so.  And found a solution.

Is question being under review this long abnormal?

Answer (score 2):

The question was put on hold as requested by you. It is in the review queue for reopenings, things usually take a while depending on how many high-rep users find time to review the queue.

I've reopened the question now to speed things up.